# itextsharp extract text pdf not working

Tags: itext

I'm having trouble getting the text from the page.

**Object reference error not set to an instance of an object**, in the bold line.

**String extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i);**

Follow the code below

```
 var pdfText = new StringBuilder();
 using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(cbPdf.SelectedValue + ""))
 {
      for (var i = 0; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
      {
         String extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i);
         extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
         pdfText.Append(extractText);
      }
 }
 rtxtTexto.Text = pdfText.ToString();
```

Comment: not quite clear what are you asking. do you get any errors?

Comment: Apparently they got Object reference error not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText numbers pages 1-based, i.e. the first page has number 1.

You already did take that into account at the end of your loop (by comparing using `<=`), merely not at the start (where you start at 0).

Thus,

```
for (var i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
```

---

That being said, as far as I know your line

```
extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
```

is nonsense.